# Find all solutions of the recurrence relation $a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} + 2^n + 3n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

**Question:**
Find all solutions of the recurrence relation $a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} +  2^n + 3n$ (*Hint:* Look for a particular solution of the form $qn2^n + p_1n + p_2$, where $q, p_1, p_2$ are constants).

**Attempt:**
The *Hint* indicates that the solution is of the form $qn2^n + p_1n + p_2$, thus

$$a_n = qn2^n + p_1n + p_2\\\iff a_n = qn2^n + p_1n + p_2= 5(qn2^{n-1} + p_1(n-1) + p_2) - 6(qn2^{n-2} + p_1(n-2) + p_2) + 2^n + 3n$$

I just need if this is a right approach, since I've already wasted hours solving this and I keep getting minute calculation error since my paper is not big enough (I write big apparently). I know for sure that $p_1 = \dfrac{3}{2}$. If my approach above is correct, I'll let this question rest.

**Edit:**
I think the hint is given due to the fact that $2^n + 3n$ looks nothing like *linear homogenous recurrence* nor does it even look like a "typical" *linear nonhomogenous recurrence relation*, since $2^n + 3n$. You might want to comment about that, but I think this book will cover this in future chapters.

Comment: I don't know a lot about recurrence relations, but this particular relationship corresponds to the differential equation $6f(x)-5f'(x)+f''(x)=e^{2x}+3xe^x$, where $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_nx^n}{n!}$. This is not an atypical differential equation in that context, and is solved with an annihilator. Then the coefficients of the power series of the solution (which is in terms of exponentials) is the explicit solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the LHS as
$$ q(n-1)2^n+q2^n+p_1n+p_2$$
and the RHS as
$$ q(n-1)2^n+(\frac{3q}{2}+1)2^n+(3-p_1)n+(7p_1-p_2) $$ 
Then compare the coefficients of $2^n$, $n$ and the constant term to get
$$ q=\frac{3q}{2}+1,p_1=3-p_1,p_2=7p_1-p_2 $$
from which you can have
$$ q=-2,p_1=\frac{3}{2},p_2=\frac{21}{4}. $$

Comment: No one has ever thought me that kind of algebraic manipulation. Since you've answered, this saved me ALOT OF writing. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @JoeyAndres, you are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I love characteristic equation mathod, so

\begin{equation}\label{1}
a_n -5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}=2^n+3n
\end{equation}

If we decrease index by 1 and multiply equation by 2, we get

\begin{equation}\label{2}
2a_{n-1}-10a_{n-2} = 2^n + 6(n-1) 
\end{equation}

Now if we substract the second equation from the first, we will get

\begin{equation}
a_n - 7a_{n-1} + 10a_{n-2} = 6-3n
\end{equation}

Now, we decrease the index agian and get

\begin{equation}
a_{n-1}-7a_{n-2} +10a_{n-3} = 6-3(n-1)
\end{equation}

After another substitution we get

$$a_n-8a_{n-1}+17a_{n-2}-10a_{n-3} = 3$$

And again

$$a_{n-1}-8a_{n-2}+17a_{n-3}-10a_{n-4} = 3$$

and we finaly get

$$a_n-9a_{n-1}+25a_{n-2}-27a_{n-3} + 10a_{n-4} = 0$$

Characteristic equation of this recursion is

$$x^4-9x^3+25x^2-27x+10 = 0$$

od

$$(x-1)^2\cdot(x-2)\cdot (x-5) = 0 $$

so, the solution of the recurrence is

$$a_n = C_1\cdot 1^n + C_2\cdot n\cdot 1^n + c_3\cdot 2^n + C_4\cdot 5^n.$$

or

$$a_n = C_1 + C_2\cdot n + c_3\cdot 2^n + C_4\cdot 5^n.$$

Answer (score 3):

We can also solve the recurrence using generating functions. We first convert the given recurrence:

$$ a_n = 5a_{n - 1} - 6a_{n - 2} + 2^n + 3n $$

into a power series by adding up all the elements of the recurrence:

$$ \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 5a_n x^{n + 1} - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 6 a_n x^{n + 2} + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} 2^n x^n + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} 3nx^n$$

Letting $F(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ we can rewrite above:

$$ F(x) - a_0 - a_1 x = 5x(F(x) - a_0) - 6x^2F(x) + \sum_{2}^{\infty} 2^n x^n + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} 3nx^n $$

The choice of $x$ is arbitrary so we may choose an $x$ such that $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} 2^n x^n$ converges, getting:

$$ F(x) - a_0 - a_1 x = 5x(F(x) - a_0) - 6x^2F(x) + \frac{1}{1 - 2x} - 1 - 2x + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} 3nx^n $$

and for the last term we reason similarly:

$$ \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} 3nx^n = \frac{3x}{(1 - x)^2} - 3x = \frac{3x^2(2 - x)}{(1 - x)^2} $$

And so:

$$ F(x) - a_0 - a_1 x = 5x(F(x) - a_0) - 6x^2F(x) + \frac{1}{1 - 2x} - 1 - 2x + \frac{3x^2(2 - x)}{(1 - x)^2} $$

Rearranging for $F(x)$ we get:

$$ (1 - 2x)(1 - 3x) F(x) = a_0 - 1 + (a_1 - 5a_0 - 2)x + \frac{3x^2(2 - x)}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac{1}{1 - 2x}$$

$$ (1 - 2x)(1 - 3x) F(x) = a + bx + \frac{3x^2(2 - x)}{(1 - x)^2} + \frac{1}{1 - 2x}$$

with $a = a_0 - 1$ and $b = a_1 - 5a_0 - 2$. Which means:

$$ F(x) = \frac{a + bx}{(1 - 2x)(1 - 3x)} + \frac{3x^2(2 - x)}{(1 - x)^2(1 - 2x)(1 - 3x)} + \frac{1}{(1 - 2x)^2(1 - 3x)} $$

Applying partial fraction decomposition to the middle term of above we get:

$$ \frac{3x^2(2 - x)}{(1 - x)^2(1 - 2x)(1 - 3x)} = \frac{15}{4} \frac{1}{1 - x} + \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} - 9\frac{1}{1 - 2x} + \frac{15}{4} \frac{1}{1 - 3x} $$

and to the first term, getting:

$$ \frac{a + bx}{(1 - 2x)(1 - 3x)} = \frac{-2a - b}{1 - 2x} + \frac{3a + b}{1 - 3x} $$

and similarly for the last term:

$$ \frac{1}{(1 - 2x)^2(1 - 3x)} = \frac{-6}{1 - 2x} - \frac{2}{(1 - 2x)^2} + \frac{9}{1 - 3x}$$

And so we have:

$$ F(x) = \frac{-2a - b}{1 - 2x} + \frac{3a + b}{1 - 3x} + \frac{15}{4} \frac{1}{1 - x} + \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} - 15 \frac{1}{1 - 2x} + \frac{51}{4} \frac{1}{1 - 3x} - \frac{2}{(1 - 2x)^2} $$

Converting above back to power series gives us the solution to the recurrence relation. We work out an example. For simplicity we let $a,b = 1$, which means $a_0 = 2$ and $a_1 = 13$. This gives us:

$$ F(x) = \frac{15}{4} \frac{1}{1 - x} + \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} - 18 \frac{1}{1 - 2x} + \frac{67}{4} \frac{1}{1 - 3x} - 2 \frac{1}{(1 - 2x)^2} $$

Now we construct the power series from above:

$$ F(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^n = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{15}{4} x^n + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{3}{2} (n + 1) x^n - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 18 \cdot 2^n x^n + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{67}{4} 3^n x^n - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2^{n + 1}(n + 1)x^n $$

Which means:

$$ a_n = \frac{15}{4} + \frac{3}{2} (n + 1) - 18 \cdot 2^n + \frac{67}{4} 3^n - 2^{n + 1}(n + 1) $$

Which is equivalent to:

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{4} \left( 21 - 2n(2^{n + 2} - 3) + 67 \cdot 3^n - 5 \cdot 2^{n + 4} \right) $$

Which is the form given in [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=T%28n%29+%3D+5T%28n+-+1%29+-+6T%28n+-+2%29+%2B+2%5En+%2B+3n%2C+T%280%29+%3D+2%2C+T%281%29+%3D+13).

***Note***:

Solving the general form for $F(x)$ we get:

$$ a_n = (3a_0 - a_1 - 11)2^n + (-2a_0 + a_1 + \frac{31}{4})3^n + \frac{15}{4} + \frac{3}{2} (n + 1) - 2^{n + 1} (n + 1) $$

Comment: Note that using generating functions avoids having to use the hint, though the approach takes a bit more effort. The advantage is it can be applied in general.